# Oracle sql developer - export DDL - only create table sql

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb, h2, ddl

I want to run unit tests by generating all tables in HSQLDB, present in my oracle database.

For that I want to export all DDL create table statements from oracle tables.

I tried export database, but along with create table sql I am getting lot other SQLs like,

" PARTITION BY RANGE ("CREATION_DATE") " etc.

How do I export all oracle tables(schema) to HSQLDB? is there any better way?

Comment: that's probably because your tables are partitioned - that is part of the ddl dyntax. it's ok.

Comment: write some regular expressions to filter out the Oracle specific stuff that are not needed by HSQLDB.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1019414) function to get the table definition, and modify what is included with the [SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1000135) options, specifically in this case the `PARTITIONING` parameter.

There are lots of examples for you to search for, but [here's one that shows the DDL being simplified](http://nuijten.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/just-plain-ddl-please-dbmsmetadata.html) with similar transformations.

Answer (score 0):

It's some work, but you can implement your own tool to create the DDL.

All you need is stored in the Oracle database catalogue.

To create just tables (without index and constraints) you need these 2 tables:

- USER_TAB_COLUMNS
- USER_TABLES

You will find a detailed documentation of these tablese here:
[Oracle Database Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5480.htm#REFRN26286)

Other usefull Oracle tables are

- USER_CONSTRAINTS
- USER_INDEXES