# How can i ignore create portioned script from create table script using get_ddl in oracle?

Tags: oracle, dbms-metadata

I am working on java project in which we are getting create table ddl using `get_ddl` method in `Oracle 12c`.

For example my table name is **PARENT_EMP** and schema is **SECONDARYUSER** then I am using get_ddl method.

```
select dbms.get_ddl('TABLE','PARENT_EMP','SECONDARYUSER') from dual;
```

before executing above statement I am executing following script to ignore constrainst and table spaces from ddl.

```
begin
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false);
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'REF_CONSTRAINTS', false);
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false); 
        dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'CONSTRAINTS', false);           
end;
```

But my issue is, some of table has REFERENCE PARTITIONED and if I get ddl using get_ddl method then also I am getting foreign constraint script.

Parent table DDl is :-

```
 create table parent_emp(
    empno      number  primary key,
    job        varchar2(20),
    sal        number(7,2),
    deptno     number(2)
    )
    partition by list(job)
    ( partition p_job_dba values ('DBA'),
      partition p_job_mgr values ('MGR'),
     partition p_job_vp  values ('VP')
   );
```

Child table DDl is :

```
  CREATE TABLE "SECONDARYUSER"."REFERENCE_EMP" 
   (    
    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "EMP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPNO" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_EMPNO" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPNO")
      REFERENCES "SECONDARYUSER"."PARENT_EMP" ("EMPNO") ENABLE
   ) 
  PARTITION BY REFERENCE ("FK_EMPNO") 
 (PARTITION "P_JOB_DBA" , 
 PARTITION "P_JOB_MGR" , 
 PARTITION "P_JOB_VP" ) "
```

Please suggest how can I get child table ddl without getting foreign constraint and partitioned ddl , or how can I creating portioned on already created table using alter table.
Also is there any way to get partitioned ddl using `get_ddl` method?

Comment: the child table ddl it's wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer.

You are missing this declaration:

```
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PARTITIONING',false);
```

Include it, and it will ignore the part with 'partition'.

So, you need those ones:

```
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS',false);
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'REF_CONSTRAINTS',false);
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PARTITIONING',false);
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
```

Credits: one of the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348486/oracle-sql-developer-export-ddl-only-create-table-sql).

Comment: I am doing same but if table has reference partitioned then getting constraint and partitioned script. how can ignore partitioned script.

Comment: Thank you this command is working . After execute this command i am getting script without partitioned but foreign key script are still coming into script.`CREATE TABLE "SECONDARYUSER"."REFERENCE_EMP" 
   ( "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
 "EMP_ID" NUMBER, 
 "EMPNO" NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT "FK_EMPNO" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPNO")
   REFERENCES "SECONDARYUSER"."PARENT_EMP" ("EMPNO") ENABLE
   ) `

Comment: I just edited again. Try to execute again, like in my post and see if works.

Comment: I have already use that script only  PARTITIONING are missing so i have add into script.